# Unexpected result on solving some inequality in Matlab symbolic computation

Tags: matlab, solver, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

Please consider this example. I would like to solve x^3 - 2x > 0. I try the following commands:

```
syms x;
f = @(x) x^3-2*x;
solve(f(x)>0,x)
```

and Matlab returns this

> ans =   solve([0.0 < x^3 - 2.0*x], [x])

which is not what I expect. Therefore I use

```
solve(f(x)+x>x,x)
```

which returns

> ans =    Dom::Interval(2^(1/2), Inf)   Dom::Interval(-2^(1/2), 0)

Can someone explain that why `solve` works successfully only in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `Real` option to `solve`:

```
solve(f(x)>0,x,'Real',1)

ans =

 Dom::Interval(2^(1/2), Inf)
 Dom::Interval(-2^(1/2), 0)
```

Comment: Or define `x` as real, e.g., `syms x real`.